# ms-access 2007 runtime and lockWindowUpdate

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

The use of lockWindowUpdate API in VBA code avoids screen flickering when updating screen content. It also greatly improve calculation delays, as the computer  do not have to refresh the screen after each calculation\update made on the underlying recordset.

Unfortunately, I cannot have it work correctly with Access 2007 runtime! On some screens, it will take 30 times more to Access 2007 users to have their data updated than Access 2003 runtime users!

By googling a little bit, I found that a similar problem [related to powerpoint 2007](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3729545.php) was also debated, but nothing, or no clear solution, appeared for msAccess. I will highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Why use an API for what VBA provides already? DoCmd.Echo False, Me.Painting = False and Application.Echo False all control screen painting. The key issues are choosing the right one for context, calling it in the right place, and providing error handling to turn it back on if there's an error.

Comment: Thanks for help. Solution works. but WHY didn't we use it before???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to test with access 2007 but would using

```
Application.Echo False ,”Updating”
```

Work for you? Just remember to turn echo back on after the code completes and in any error trapping

```
Application.Echo True,””
```

Comment: Up to now, it works! I just had to update my freezeForm and unfreezeForm functions in the app. The question is now: how did we NOT find this solution before even thinking of using windows API???

Comment: Ahh dont worry these things happen, I spent ages making my own auto front end updater widget only to find there was already one out there! I'm sure I will continue to make other such "mistakes" in the future!

Comment: Plus I have tons of production code with custom functions that do things that Access started providing 10 years ago. As well as functions that do things that Access already did when I wrote them. :(